# jQuery view 20 from contents

Tags: jquery

This is for an ads page. By default it shows only 20 ads at end of the ads. There is a text, if you click on it you can see another 20, again at the end we display text, if you click on it you can view another 20.

The problem is I want it to show the ads without clicking but by scrolling.

Here is the jQuery code I have written which is not working, since `i` is not static.

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var i=1600;
  if(scroll>i){
    $(".pagescroll").trigger("click");
    i+=2400;    
  }   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you're resetting the value of `i` to 1600 on every scroll so it will never work twice. Try setting it outside of the scope of the `scroll` callback and updating that scope once you pass your given threshold.

```
var myApp = {}
myApp.scrollPoint = 1600;

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(scroll>myApp.scrollPoint){
    myApp.scrollPoint+=2400;    
  }   
});
```

Here's a working example snippet:

```js
var myApp = {}
myApp.scrollPoint = 300;
myApp.update = $('#test span')

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  myApp.update.text(scroll);
  if (scroll > myApp.scrollPoint) {
    $(".pagescroll").trigger("click");
    myApp.scrollPoint += 400;
  }
});

//demo
$(".pagescroll").on('click', function() {
  //a little off due to scrolling and time it takes to run this
  var curPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('#test').append('<p>Clicked. Currently at ' + curPosition + '</p>');
})
```

```css
/* All CSS for demo only */

#test {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: #fff;
}
section {
  padding-top: 150px;
  line-height: 4;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  <h1>  Position: <span></span> </h1>
</div>
<span class="pagescroll"></span>

<section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos delectus similique sapiente necessitatibus, quia rem, pariatur ea unde eos deleniti eum illum a adipisci neque velit sed vitae mollitia ullam.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Ipsum corporis eum, ratione deleniti labore quia facere quas. Dolorum perspiciatis, tempora doloribus. Architecto, impedit, aut rem praesentium mollitia neque eius perferendis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi
  assumenda quos impedit eaque harum repudiandae necessitatibus, inventore officia tempore, minima pariatur hic quam nisi est maiores. Nemo cupiditate nihil, recusandae.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis esse reiciendis
  harum minima officiis quidem temporibus sunt nemo voluptatum. Maxime, suscipit, molestias aliquid laborum nesciunt neque asperiores beatae ducimus illo.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos consequuntur aliquam placeat soluta
  dolorum, impedit porro adipisci laudantium dolores sit modi! Quae assumenda minima, id animi iusto dignissimos nihil excepturi?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae consequuntur odit deleniti modi ex, voluptatum maxime
  harum dicta ratione, nemo, fugiat a, debitis eligendi facere quidem iure exercitationem. Sapiente, repellat.</section>
```